# Finding nCk if n and k are given using modular inversion

Tags: c++, modulo

Given two integers `n` and `k`, it is expected to find `nCk % MOD` , where `MOD` is `1000000007`. My program is as follows:

```
long long int MOD = 1000000007;

long long int fast_pow(long long int base, long long int n,long long int M)
{
    if(n==0)
       return 1;
    if(n==1)
    return base;
    long long int halfn=fast_pow(base,n/2,M);
    if(n%2==0)
        return ( (halfn%M) * (halfn%M) ) % M;
    else
        return ( ( ( (halfn%M) * (halfn%M) ) % M ) * (base%M) ) % M;
}
long long int findMMI_fermat(long long int n,long long int M)
{
    return fast_pow(n,M-2,M);
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        long long int n,k;
        cin>>n>>k;
        k=min(k,n-k);
        long long int ans = 1;
        for(long long int i=0;i<k;++i)
            ans=(((ans*(n-i))%MOD)*findMMI_fermat(i+1,MOD))%MOD;// findMMI_fermat is to find the modular inverse
        cout<<(ans)%MOD<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the online judge says the solution is wrong. Can anyone suggest where the code may be going wrong?
**NOTE:** My logic is to run a loop `ans*=(n-i)/(i+1)` where `i` runs from `0` to `k-1`.

Comment: Could you provide a set of entries when the 'online judge' says that the solution is wrong ?

Comment: @J.Piquard Unfortunately I cannot access the wrong test-case...Here is the problem link https://www.codechef.com/problems/NOWAYS

Comment: In the description of the 'NOWAYS' problem, the **Input** is described as _The first line of the input contains an integer t, number of test cases next t lines follow with each line containing two integers (n and k) separated by space._ assuming that the entry shall be a text file. Are you sure that your 'online judge' is not excepted that format ?

Comment: @J.Piquard, I guess this is not the problem as I have submitted solutions on this judge before....